# AutoClose HttpURLConnection same as DB Connection(using try-with-resourse) in JAVA

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Auto closing HttpURLConnection (same as DB Connection using try-with-resourse)
here i am looking for closing HttpURLConnection,without closing manually ex:urlConnection.disconnect(); in finally block

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same, but you can write a wrapper class for `Autocloseable` that kind of does it for you.

```
class AutocloseWrapper<T> implements Autocloseable {
    T wrapped;
    Consumer<T> closeMethod;
    public AutocloseWrapper(T wrapped, Consumer<T> closeMethod) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped; this.closeMethod = closeMethod;
    }
    public void close() {
        closeMethod.accept(wrapped);
    }
}
```

And you'd call that with

```
private void yourMethod() {
    HttpUrlConnection connection = createConnection();
    try (AutocloseWrapper wrapper = new AutocloseWrapper(connection, HttpUrlConnection::disconnect)) {
        // do your stuff with the connection
    }
    // connection.disconnect() will have been called here
}
```